# Combing temp tables in series

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Say, I have 6 temp tables stored as the following (those 3 are samples) and I would to form them into 1 single table, to be in series (headers Date, Com, Price).

```
Com A
Date                      Price 
2015-05-01 00:00:00.000   34.25
2015-05-02 00:00:00.000   35.20
2015-05-03 00:00:00.000   36.70 
2015-05-04 00:00:00.000   32.37
2015-05-05 00:00:00.000   32.40
2015-05-06 00:00:00.000   32.20  


Com B
Date                      Price 
2015-05-07 00:00:00.000   54.29
2015-05-08 00:00:00.000   54.50
2015-05-09 00:00:00.000   56.21
2015-05-10 00:00:00.000   56.70
2015-05-11 00:00:00.000   58.20 

Com C
Date                      Price 
2015-05-12 00:00:00.000   34.29
2015-05-13 00:00:00.000   24.50
2015-05-14 00:00:00.000   76.21
2015-05-15 00:00:00.000   36.70
2015-05-16 00:00:00.000   48.20
```

The output to look like, and I would like to store it as another temp table for merging later:

```
Date                      Com   Price 
2015-05-01 00:00:00.000   A     34.25
2015-05-02 00:00:00.000   A     35.20
2015-05-03 00:00:00.000   A     36.70 
2015-05-04 00:00:00.000   A     32.37
2015-05-05 00:00:00.000   A     32.40
2015-05-06 00:00:00.000   A     32.20  
2015-05-07 00:00:00.000   B     54.29
2015-05-08 00:00:00.000   B     54.50
2015-05-09 00:00:00.000   B     56.21
2015-05-10 00:00:00.000   B     56.70
2015-05-11 00:00:00.000   B     58.20 
2015-05-12 00:00:00.000   C     34.29
2015-05-13 00:00:00.000   C     24.50
2015-05-14 00:00:00.000   C     76.21
2015-05-15 00:00:00.000   C     36.70
2015-05-16 00:00:00.000   C     48.20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a simple `union all` to me:

```
SELECT [Date], 'A' as Com, Price
FROM [Com A]

UNION ALL

SELECT [Date], 'B' as Com, Price
FROM [Com B]

UNION ALL

SELECT [Date], 'C' as Com, Price
FROM [Com C]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data

```
Select Date,'A' AS Com,Price from [COM A]
UNION ALL
Select Date,'B' AS Com,Price from [COM B]
UNION ALL
Select Date,'C' AS Com,Price from [COM C]
```